# Unwinding and summing up subsubdocuments with MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

Here's a basic abtract schema I am working with:

```js
var activity = {
  _id: ObjectId,
  occurrences: [{
    _id: ObjectId,
    date: Date,
    followers: [ ObjectID ],
    attendances: [{
      answer: String   
    }]
  }]
}
```

Sample document:

```js
var activity = {
  _id: '123',
  occurrences: [{
    _id: '111',
    followers: [
      '777',
      '888'
    ],
    attendances: [{
      answer: 'yes'
    }, {
      answer: 'no'
    }]  
  }, {
    _id: '222',
    followers: [
      '555',
      '666'
    ],
    attendances: [{
      answer: 'yes'
    }, {
      answer: 'yes'
    }]
  }]
}
```

Using the aggregation pipeline I would like to break this down into individual occurrences each of which contains the number of attendances whose answer matches a string (i.e. "yes"). I can break things down into individual occurrences but am experiencing difficulties with the further breakdown. The result correctly shows each occurrences with their attendances but the followers count is totally wrong.  I may have made things way more complicated then I need also:

Here's my non working attempt:

```js
this.aggregate({
    $unwind: '$occurences'
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$occurences._id',
      attendances: {
        $first: "$occurences.attendances"
      },
      followers: {
        $first: "$occurences.followers"
      },
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: '$attendances'
  }, {
    $match: {
      "attendances.answer": {
        $ne: "no"
      }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      attendances: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      followers: {
        $sum: {
          $size: {
            $ifNull: ["$followers", []]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
      attendances: 1,
      followers: 1,
    }
  }
);
```

I would like this result:

```js
[{ _id: 111, attendances: 1, followers: 2 },
 { _id: 222, attendances: 2, followers: 2 }]
```

Comment: There is no field called `occurs`, in the group call it should be a occurences. Typo I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your query a little bit simpler by using the [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator to get the followers count. You will still need to unwind the attendances array to filter out the "no" answers and then group to get the attendances count.

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$occurrences"
}, 
{
    $project : { 
        _id : 1,
        occurrenceId : "$occurrences._id",
        followers: { $size: "$occurrences.followers" }, 
        attendances : "$occurrences.attendances"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$attendances"
}, 
{
    $match: {
      "attendances.answer": "yes"
    }
}, 
{
    $group: {
      _id: { id: "$_id", occurrenceId : "$occurrenceId"},
      followers : { $first : "$followers" },
      attendances: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
}]);
```

**Edit**

The result I got using your sample document is :

```js
{"_id": { "id": "123", "occurrenceId": "222" }, "followers": 2, "attendances": 2}
{"_id": { "id": "123", "occurrenceId": "111" }, "followers": 2, "attendances": 1}
```

Comment: That correctly adds up the followers but the attendances count is wrong now - seems to be reflecting the total attendances for all occurrences in an activity rather than just for one

Comment: @Yashua if the occurrence id is repeated in multiple documents the count will be wrong. I fixed the query so that it groups the documents by the _id and occurrence id. The query will now count correctly attendances for each document.

Comment: Each occurrence occurs only once. Additionally your ealier code uses the activity id in the final grouping. Seems that I may need to work off of 2 groups as I'd like to end up with a cleaner structure than the latest proposed one.

Comment: Figured it out - needed to use $avg instead of $sum

Comment: @Yashua then your structure and/or data doesn't match the sample you posted or you weren't clear with the result you're expecting.

Comment: Ah I have found the issue - it was a typo I had (_id instead of id). Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. The follower count was wrong because the unwind operation on the attendances was creating multiple entries each with the same followers. Instead of using $sum which added them all up I needed to use $avg.

```
this.aggregate({
    $unwind: '$occurences'
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$occurences._id',
      attendances: {
        $first: "$occurences.attendances"
      },
      followers: {
        $first: "$occurences.followers"
      },
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: '$attendances'
  }, {
    $match: {
      "attendances.answer": {
        $ne: "no"
      }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      attendances: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      followers: {
        $avg: {
          $size: {
            $ifNull: ["$followers", []]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```